# How to get element where class name is not equal to value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would simply like to find out how to get an element where the class name is not equal to the value passed in. E.g:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#allRolesDD', function () {
        var toShow = document.getElementsByClassName($(this).val());
//Below line is the one where I want to get the value where the class name is not equal to the value
        var toHide = document.getElementsByClassName(!$(this).val());
        alert($(toHide).html());
        toHide.attr('hidden', true);
        toShow.show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `:not`, `$('selector:not(.hateThisClass)')`

Comment: Why mix up `jQuery` with `Vanilla JS`?. Choose one way and go for that.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Yeah, I will just use Javascript

Comment: That's unclear question. Select element without specific class doesn't mean something if you don't provide some way to filter it out. What about parent of element with class `$(this).val()`???

Answer (score 3):

Use [`:not` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('selector:not(.hateThisClass)')
```

You can also use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) to *"Remove elements from the set of matched elements."*

```
$('selector').not('.hateThisClass')
```

---

Complete Code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#allRolesDD', function () {
    var toShow = '.' + $(this).val();

    $(toShow).show();
    $(':not(' + toShow + ')').hide(); // Assumed the elements need to hide, not just adding an attribute
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the :not selector.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) is the full documentation for that.
Usage example

```
  XX:not(<class>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up pure JavaScript and jQuery, use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to filter out like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#allRolesDD', function () {
        var toShow = $("." + $(this).val());
        //Below line is the one where I want to get the value where the class name is not equal to the value
        // make sure you define your parent here.
        var toHide = $(parent).find(":not(." + $(this).val() + ")");
        alert($(toHide).html());
        toHide.prop('hidden', true);
        toShow.show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `":not(." + $(this).val() + ")"` will select many many elements, even the parents of `"." + $(this).val()`, e.g `html` :)